# logger.info is throwing null pointer exception when whole maven project is run under junit test

Tags: java, maven, logging, junit, slf4j

Here is the example code

```
class Temp
{
    public static int someMethod()
    {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Temp.class);
        logger.info("Some information");//NullPointerException
        return 0;
    }
}

class ClassToTest
{
    public int methodToTest()
    {
        Temp tempInstance = new Temp();
        int i = temp.someMethod();
        return i;
    }
}

class TestAClass
{
    ClassToTest classToTestInstance;
    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        classToTestInstance = new ClassToTest();
    }
    @Test
    public void testMethodToTest()
    {
        int i = classToTest.methodToTest();
    }
}
```

This is a sceneario. This test case may pass. But in actual code when I run the individual test cases or run the whole test class, Test case passes but when I run the maven project under junit test It fails with NullPointerException. I can not post actual code because it is a proprietary code. Please guide me if someone has faced this type of issue.

Stack trace which I am getting when I run my actual code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.info(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:304)
    at Temp
    at ClassToTest
    at TestAClass
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.JUnit4TestRunnerDecorator.executeTestMethod(JUnit4TestRunnerDecorator.java:142)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.JUnit4TestRunnerDecorator.invokeExplosively(JUnit4TestRunnerDecorator.java:71)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(MockFrameworkMethod.java:40)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? Is the logger object null? Which logging library are you using?

Comment: No in debugging logger is not null. I am using org.slf4j library.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of where the NPE is originating?

Comment: Stack trace added in question.

Comment: What is your log4j settings? Does it happen when you move the class to some package instead of the default one?

Comment: How can I find my log4j setting? No class is in default package.

Comment: Have you specified the test scope for the junit dependency in your pom.xml? `<scope>test</scope>`

Comment: Yes I have.
`<dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.11</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Can you share the relevant lines of `<dependency>` declaration for `slf4j` - specifically if you have added `slf4j-log4j` or any other binding?

Comment: `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.7</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: @Varun I create a small project on https://github.com/SubOptimal/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/question-26338982. Run it as "mvn -X -Dtest=TestAClass test" and then run you own the same amend the class names) and check if there is an error/warning reported for some depenedency.

Comment: @SubOptimal I am not getting NullPoinetrException in this code which I posted, but I am getting this type of error in my other code which I can't post here.

Comment: @Varun check the dependencies `mvn dependency:tree` and compare the dependency tree for `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12` and `junit:junit:jar:4.11` from my sample project with the output of yours.

Comment: This is my dependency tree `[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile`

Comment: Can you check your import lines for `Logger` and `LoggerFactory`.

Comment: `import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;`

Comment: @Varun last try: What happen if you run your test outside of Eclipse? Do you get the same stacktrace as you posted above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63032/discussion-between-varun-and-suboptimal).

Comment: Yes. I get same stacktrace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem was due to because `logger` was `static` in `Temp` class. If instance of `Temp` class is created in another test class earlier so it can not load the `logger` for the temp class because it is already loaded. So when we run the whole project under `junit` test it fails. Because `logger` for Temp class is somewhere in other test class is already loaded. This problem is resolved by `mocking` the `logger` with `JMockit`.
@SubOptimal Thank you for giving time.

Comment: This shows why it's important to post code which reproduce the problem. ;-) Anyway, glad to hear that your problem could be solved.

Comment: You are right. But I can't post the actual because it is proprietary code. Again Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I got this exception when the Logger object was **not static** in the class by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is just an example, and it may not be wrong at your actual code.
However, I think that it would be good to let you know.

There is a correction to be made here:

```
class ClassToTest
{
    public int methodToTest()
    {
        Temp tempInstance = new Temp(); 
        // there is no need of an instance here since the method is static.
        
        int i = Temp.someMethod(); // was temp.someMethod()
        return i;
    }
}
```

And I would suggest to make logger static at your Temp.class, like this:

```
class Temp
{
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Temp.class);

    public static int someMethod()
    {
        logger.info("Some information");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same issue, then I added this piece of code to my class (In this case class Temp)

```
public class Temp {

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Temp.class);

  //Write your code

}
```