# Slf4j log.debug throws NPE inside a function bean

Tags: java, functional-programming, slf4j, spring-cloud-stream

The code below declares a function bean to supply events to message broker through cloud stream API.

I am trying to log using slf4j logger from INSIDE the function bean.
When I invoke this code from a Junit, the `log.debug()` throws a NPE.
I know this is a static logger that is wired and inside the JUNIT code the 'log' static class is present, but it throws the NPE only inside this function bean. I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338982/logger-info-is-throwing-null-pointer-exception-when-whole-maven-project-is-run-u) but still couldn't figure out why this `log.debug()` throws a NPE.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class EventSender
{
    private final Queue<Event> eventq= new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    
    /**
     * Returns a function bean that will be invoked when the spring cloud stream framework wants to poll
     * for a message and send it to the message broker.
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public Supplier<Event> msgSender()
    {
        return () -> {
            Event sysEvt = eventq.poll();
            log.debug(" Msg polled from Cloud Stream and Sent: " + sysEvt.toString());
            return sysEvt;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is unrelated to anything spring. Rather Lombok and slf4j issue. Please follow this tutorial which seems to cover it in great detail - https://roytuts.com/how-to-log-with-lombok-using-slf4j-annotation-in-java-spring-and-spring-boot-applications/